# What is the critical coupling constant in an Ising model and how to spot it?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, ising-model, critical-phenomena

Consider a zero-field Ising model with $N$ spins and periodic boundary conditions, with the Hamiltonian given by
$$H = -K \sum _{(ij)} s_i s_j$$
in 1D and 2D, where $K = \frac{J}{k_BT}$, where $J$ is the coupling constant energy. If I run a Monte Carlo simulation with $N$ particles with Metropolis sampling, how do I spot the critical $K_c$ value? Onsager's solution in 2D predicted critical $K_c = 0.4406868$.

**My question is, when I run a simulation with $N$ particles and I track the Hamiltonian per particle $(H/N)$ and the magnetization per particle $\left(\sum _i s_i /N\right)$, with $K$ values going from $0.1$ to $0.7$ in increments of $0.1$, how do I spot the region of the critical coupling constant?**

There has to be a signature of the critical point that is stronger when $K=0.4$ and $K=0.5$ that should lead me to think that the critical value of $K$ is between these two numbers, right? Also, what is the criticality condition for 1 dimension?